# Databricks Foundation - Number of Partitions on Exercise 3-d Reality Checks is failing "Found 36 Partitions"

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am currently doing the Databricks Foundational Course Exercises, where a Reality Check is failing in Exercise 3d.

**Code -**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df_batch_temp_view = spark.sql(f"select * from {batch_temp_view}")
df_batch_temp_view = (df_batch_temp_view
                     .withColumn("submitted_at", from_unixtime(col("submitted_at")).cast("timestamp"))
                     .withColumn("submitted_yyyy_mm", date_format(col("submitted_at"),"yyyy-MM"))
                     .withColumn("shipping_address_zip", col("shipping_address_zip").cast("Int"))
                     .drop("sales_rep_ssn", "sales_rep_first_name", "sales_rep_last_name", "sales_rep_address", "sales_rep_city",\
                           "sales_rep_state", "sales_rep_zip","product_id", "product_quantity", "product_sold_price")
                     .dropDuplicates(["order_id","customer_id","sales_rep_id"])
                     .select("submitted_at","submitted_yyyy_mm","order_id","customer_id","sales_rep_id",\
                             "shipping_address_attention","shipping_address_address","shipping_address_city","shipping_address_state",\
                             "shipping_address_zip","ingest_file_name","ingested_at")
                      .repartition(1)
                     )



df_batch_temp_view.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").partitionBy("submitted_yyyy_mm").saveAsTable(f"{orders_table}")
```

**My Testing**

```
spark.sql(f"show partitions {orders_table}").count()
```

Result - 36

**Problem:**
When I am doing the reality check, its showing failure in "Found 36 Partitions"
[image]

Any suggestions, not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the problem, by dropping the database and working directory. All I needed to do was to reset the whole thing and start from beginning. Mostly it was a cache issue.